# How to make editable table with .txt file as input (servlets)

Tags: java, arrays, servlets

I'm currently working on a program that will input data from a .txt file and allow the user to edit it. I have only taken a single programming class (Introduction to Java) at my university so I'm quite a beginner, but I'm always willing to learn new things. I have some thoughts on what I should be doing, but I can't seem to get past a certain area.

First, I read in the file,which is basically lists of data and then create a multidimensional array that puts each piece of data, separated by some sort of delimiter, in each element. I then create the table by inputting array elements in some nested loops and using the contenteditable attribute to make my table editable. I know how to code these part, but from here I'm stuck. I want the edits to change the value of the array elements(part I'm confused about) so I can eventually put the elements back into the original .txt file(I can do this part). How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of array use a HashMap, where string is the column name. Every time you edit a value in the table, make the necessary changes in the arraylist. When you want to update, use this Map and iterate over as desired.

Comment: You can also do with just List of List. If you have an id associated with each column and map that id to column name.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you already have the file contents in your server memory (maybe in the Session object or in the Servlet instance) and you are arleady showing these contents in an HTML or JSP page.

To send changes made in the HTML back to the server, you need to send them to a Java Servlet. The Java Servlet can have post and get methods in which they receive a `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse` parameters. You can do that in two ways:

Via common HTTP POST method. This will refresh the page and point your browser to the servlet URL so you will need to send back a response from the servlet via `response.write()` or redirect back to the original page showing again the file contents. To make sure that the data will travel to the servlet you must enclose it in a form tag and add name attributes to the modified fields. The name attribute is the key to obtain this parameter from the servlet via request.getParameeter(String).

Via Ajax. You can use plain vanilla javascript, jQuery or any other jquery helper library. In this case, you have to manually map the parameters you want to send to the servlet and expect an asynchronous response from it, which maybe you will want to parse.

Either way, your servlet will receive a request with the parameter names you configured either in your HTML form or in your ajax parameter list. You then take this parameter with `request.getParameter(paramName)` and update it in your array.

Check the [tag about servlets](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) to understand better how they work.